# Determining Maven execution phase within a plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I have a plugin which transforms the compiled classes.  This transformation needs to be done for both the module's classes and the module's test classes.  Thus, I bind the plugin to both the process-classes and process-test-classes phases.  The problem I have is that I need to determine which phase the plugin is currently executing in, as I do not (cannot, actually) transform the same set of classes twice.

Thus, within the plugin, I would need to know if I'm executing process-classes - in which case I transform the module's classes.  Or if I'm executing process-test-classes - in which I case I do not transform the module's classes and transform only the module's test classes.

I could, of course, create two plugins for this, but this kind of solution deeply offends my sensibilities and is probably against the law in several states.

It seems like something I could reach from my module should be able to tell me what the current phase is.  I just can't for the life of me find out what that something is.

Thanks...

Comment: @Pascal Thivent for the zombies processes and zombies computers :)

Comment: @Colin Yeah I got that but I don't see any relation with  the question.

Comment: I wanted to add the tag zombies-ate-my-brain but I don't have any rep, so I went with zombies

Answer (score 9):

> Thus, within the plugin, I would need to know if I'm executing process-classes (...) or if I'm executing process-test-classes

AFAIK, this is [not really possible](http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@maven.apache.org/msg70338.html).

> I could, of course, create two plugins for this, but this kind of solution deeply offends my sensibilities and is probably against the law in several states.

I don't see anything wrong with having two Mojos sharing code but bound to different phases. Something like the Maven Compiler Plugin (and its `compiler:compile` and `compiler:testCompile` goals).

Comment: Well, that answer by Dr. J is pretty definitive.  I must say that seems pretty darn weird, but what evs...  Thanks for the speedy answer.

Comment: I also discovered that the AspectJ compiler Maven plugin does the same thing as what I need to do and so I'm going to see how they dealt with this.

Comment: So, the pattern the AspectJ compiler used works for me.  For posterity, I simply create two Mojos in my plugin, one for process-classes and one for process-test-classes.  This solution doesn't require another plugin (which was my main fear).

Comment: Can't you get from the MavenExecutionRequest? Of course I ask about how to get that object.

Comment: @Hellblazer AspectJ is an even better example indeed.

Comment: Yup, in almost all Maven Plugins I implemented there was an AbstractXyzMojo, a CompileXyzMojo and a TestCompileXyzMojo. I guess that's standard for Maven Plugin development (+1)

Comment: @seanizer Yes, exactly, same here.

Answer (score 2):

you can't get the phase, but you can get the execution ID which you have as separate. In the plugin:

```
/** 
 * @parameter expression="${mojoExecution}" 
 */
private org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution execution;

...

public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException
{
    ...
    System.out.println( "executionId is: " + execution.getExecutionId() );
}
```

I'm not sure if this is portable to Maven 3 yet.

Comment: Thanks.  I just used the pattern that AspectJ uses and it works perfectly fine.  Don't want to go against the grain when Maven wants a particular pattern to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Java plugin code snippets:

```
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Component;

...

@Component
private MojoExecution execution;
...
execution.getLifecyclePhase()
```

Use Maven dependencies (your versions may vary):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>3.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This works only partially as `execution.getLifecyclePhase()` will return `null` when mojo is invoked directly (not as part of lifecycle), e.g. `mvn plugin-name:mojo-name`.