# Modify next build phases from within a maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm developing a maven plugin that performs some tasks like executing other plugins programmatically (e.g. mutation test plugin, code coverage collection plugin).

The problem I'm facing is **to programmatically check which are the next build lifecycle phases** (e.g "test", "package", "integration-test") **to be executed**.

More specifically, I want to, in some cases, skip the "test" phase from within my Maven Plugin.

My plugin is bound to execute in the "process-test-classes" phase (defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_TEST_CLASSES).

Note that I want to do this programmatically.
I tried looking at the following parameters while debugging execution:

- MavenSession (got with ${session})
- BuildPluginManager (got with @Component annotation)
- MojoExecution (got with $Component annotation)

Unfortunately I couldn't find any references to next build lifecycle phases to be executed.

I found this similar question: [Determining Maven execution phase within a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746585/determining-maven-execution-phase-within-a-plugin), but it only gives an idea on how to determine the current phase and not the next ones.

So my question is: anyone has an idea on how to approach this?

Comment: A plugin which executes other plugins ? Sounds wrong...Apart from that skipping a phase within a plugin is not possible...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for the reply. I was hoping for some maven parameter that contains current build settings which I could manipulate, like those in MavenSession. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you explain more detail what kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @khmarbaise The purpose of my plugin is to execute some tasks on a given Maven project. These tasks include injecting software faults by mutating the code (another plugin), creating a copy of the project in a designated path, collect coverage data (another plugin) and executing unit tests in a specific order for this new copy. My plugin manage all these tasks and repeat them many times. The problem I'm facing is that I do not want to execute the tests of the current project being built after the execution of my plugin (which happens just before the test phase).

Comment: So you are talking about pitest things like this? Running JaCoCo or clover etc. ? Running unit tests in a specific order means from my point of view those are not unit tests..Apart from that this is a job for a CI solution ...like Jenkins..

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, those plugins. What I'm doing is called test case prioritization and is used mainly for "optimizing" regression test runs by executing tests that are "prone" to fail first. I'm making this plugin as a tool to conduct academic research in this topic